# How to map through dynamic pages in Next13.3 to create sitemap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sitemap

I am using the recommended way to create a sitemap in Next13.3+ using a `sitemap.js` file in the app folder with the following code (obviously changing these examples for the real urls)

```
export default function sitemap() {
    return [
        {
            url: 'https://acme.com',
            lastModified: new Date(),
        },
        {
            url: 'https://acme.com/about',
            lastModified: new Date(),
        },
        {
            url: 'https://acme.com/blog',
            lastModified: new Date(),
        },
    ]
}
```

However I would like to map over the dynamically created pages in a `[slug]` folder with a `page.js` in it to create the items in the sitemap.

How can I programmatically refer to those dynamic pages in the `sitemap.js`?

I have tried using `$(slug)` in an arrow function but this does not work.

```
const routes = ["", "/$(slug]"].map((route) => ({
  url: `${URL}${route}`,
  lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
}));
return routes
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it...

```
import { getPages } from "../../sanity/sanity-utils"

const URL = "https://example.com";

export default async function sitemap() {

    const pages = await getPages();

    const routes = ["", "/*"].map((route) => ({
        url: `${URL}${route}`,
        lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));

    const pages1 = pages.map(({ slug }) => ({
        url: `${URL}/${slug}`,
        lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));

    return [...routes, ...pages1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it in file `sitemap.js`.

```js
import { getPostsForSitemap } from "../service";

const URL = "https://example.com";

export default async function sitemap() {
  const data = await getPostsForSitemap();
  const posts = data.data.map((post) => ({
    url: `${URL}/${post.attributes.slug}`,
    lastModified: post.attributes.updatedAt,
  }));

  const routes = ["/", "/about", "/contact"].map((route) => ({
    url: `${URL}${route}`,
    lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
  }));

  return [...posts, ...routes];
}
```

Please note that my api (strapi) returns list of posts with slug and last updated date.
I am doing data fetching  in function `getPostsForSitemap`.
[Here](https://stockandequity.com/sitemap.xml) is sitemap  generated using this code.